# I'm trying to copy the entire header of a template document to a new document using Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

```
   var header = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
   var headerfirst = header.getParent().getChild(2).asHeaderSection();
   var template = DocumentApp.openByUrl("url here").getHeader();
   var templatefirst = template.getParent().getChild(2).asHeaderSection();

   header.clear();
   headerfirst.clear();
   headerfirst.setHeader(templatefirst); << There is no such function
   ui.alert("here");
```

I've written some code for a Google document that's supposed to grab the header/first page header from a template document (template and templatefirst), and set the current document's header to the header of the template, with all formatting intact.

This header contains images, a table, and plenty of text formatting: I don't think it'd work to simply use "replaceText" or "setText", as I'd like for the formatting of the template to be preserved, too.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try using the [copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section#copy) method of the [Class HeaderSection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section#top_of_page). It "Returns a detached, deep copy of the current element where any child elements present in the element are also copied."

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs Doesn't seem to have a way to put the entire header in at once, but I was able to successfully copy all the children in one header and add them all into the second without data loss. All my childtypes were paragraph, despite having images in my header, so I only had to append paragraphs.

```
function myFunction() {
var header = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
var doc2 = DocumentApp.openById(id);
doc2.getHeader();
var childCount = header.getNumChildren();
for (var i = 0; i<childCount; i++){
  var currentChild = header.getChild(i).copy();
  var type = currentChild.getType();
  doc2.getHeader().appendParagraph(currentChild);
}
}
```